# Arbitrarily "isolated" primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $\{p_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be the increasing sequence of the prime numbers.

It is well known that $\{p_{n+1}-p_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not bounded. But is there any result about 
$$\{\min(p_{n+2}-p_{n+1},p_{n+1}-p_n)\}_{n\in\Bbb N}?$$

In other words: for each $m\in\Bbb N$, is there a prime $p>m$ such that the interval $[p-m,p+m]$ contains no more primes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Let $q$ be a prime greater than $m+1$. 
Set $I= \{2, \dots, q-1\} \cup \{q+1, \dots, 2q-1\}$ and let $M = \operatorname{lcm} I$. Then $q \nmid M$ so $\gcd (q,M)=1$.

Thus there exists a prime $p$ of the form $q + nM $ with $n \ge 1$.
No other element in  $[p-(q-2), p+(q-1)]$ can be a prime as its $\gcd$ with $M$ is not $1$.